# Using Ubuntu as a network file server - options to remote in from other locations?

Tags: server, samba, ftp

I recently bought a new machine I'm planning to use as a file server. I've utilized Samba and created a share, etc - which I can access from my Windows machines on the network.

I was curious though, let's say I'm travelling for work and I'd like to remote into the server to access those files.

Should I do just a normal RDP solution, an FTP server, or is there some other more efficient/better method to solely access those files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What is better is a matter of opinion. Opinion based questions are off topic here. You may want to frame your question in a more objective criteria. I like `sftp` better. Others may have other options.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. Which one is best for you depends on your needs, your skills, and other circumstances. To name a few:

1. You can set up a VPN to connect your Windows machine to your network and access everything the same way as locally.
2. You can set up a Nextcloud server and access your files through the Nextcloud client.
3. You can set up a Windows VM and use it like a terminal server, connecting to it via RDP. (Preferably over a VPN.)
4. You can set up remote access via ssh (preferably with public key authentication) and access your files via scp or sftp.

Note: I'd recommend against FTP because it is an outdated and insecure protocol.